# Excel Table to List

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a plugin or a Macro to convert in Excel a table to a List. I could develop a VB code for this but it looks as a problem other people might already have solved.

A simplified verison of the problem is :

Source

```
-       -        -       2010 2009 
Spain  Male  Population   54    53
Spain  Femal Population   64    63
Spain  Male  PIB          2     3
```

Result

```
Spain  Male  Population  2010 54 
Spain  Male  Population  2009 53 
Spain  Femal Population  2010 64
Spain  Femal Population  2010 63
...
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do a lot with Excel and ADO. There is plenty in SO on the subject.

Comment: Jean-Francois, "I'm looking for a plugin" -> I don't want to do the VB Code myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-order your data with several `OFFSET` formulae

If your data was in A:E

- in G1 put `=OFFSET(A$2,(ROW()-1)/2,0)` and copy to colulm I and down
- In H1 put `=OFFSET($D$1,,MOD(ROW()+1,2)) and copy down
- in I1 put`=OFFSET($D$2,INT(ROW()-1)/2,MOD(ROW()+1,2))`

This can be run in VBA if you like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's just an example with data the actual data is lot bigger

Comment: @icCube does this mean you need more help, or more of an explanation as to how it works? If we don't get the full scope of your intent its hard to tailor an answer to your needs :)